# Eloquent return wrong primary key result with Datatables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, yajra-datatable

I have a problem with an eloquent result using Datatables component.

This is my code:

```
$licences = Licence::with(['purchase.company', 'catalog_package.catalog', 'catalog_package.package', 'createdContact']);

return Datatables::of($licences)
    ->addColumn('actions', function (Licence $licence) {
    $ret = '<a href="'. url("/") .'/licences/edit/'. $licence->id .'" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="'. ucfirst(trans("messages.edit")) .'"><i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i></a>';
        return $ret;
    })
    ->rawColumns(['actions', 'end_date'])
    ->make();
```

The result of `$licence->id` is wrong: I expect to have 1 but I get 2.

I think that it is confused with the relationships?

I tried to run `dd($licence)` inside `addColumn` and there I found that all the values are correct except for id.

Do you know why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know that `1` is correct but `2` is not ? I only see a query without any filter. Tell us what are you doing (paginating maybe) where you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

According to Yajra Documentation you should add `->select('licences.*')` statement to your eloquent query when using eager load "to avoid weird issues where id from related model replaces the id of the main model".

```
$licences = Licence::with(['purchase.company', 'catalog_package.catalog', 'catalog_package.package', 'createdContact'])->select('licences.*');
```

[https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/relationships#:~:text=It%20is%20advised%20that%20you%20include%20select(%27table.*%27)](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/relationships#:%7E:text=It%20is%20advised%20that%20you%20include%20select(%27table.*%27))

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30459418)

Comment: edited. sorry my bad.